# Trouble with jQuery Script for On click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My code seems to not run the jQuery at all for some reason, I have spent lots of time attempting to figure out what's wrong and have tested my delete PHP file separately

jQuery script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', '#btn',function()) {
        var clickBtnName = $(this).attr('name');
        var ajaxurl = 'http://127.0.0.1/SQLDeleteHandler.php';
        var data = {'id': clickBtnName};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            window.location.href="http://localhost/store.php";
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts";

$resultset= mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset,MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]." ".'<input type="submit" class="btn" name="".$row[0]."" value="delete" />';
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: did you get any error in the console

Comment: Additional `)` in `function())`, you must be getting error in browser console and it should be `'.btn'`

Comment: Additional quotes `"` here `name="".$row[0].""`

Comment: What is shown in console? Ajax is calling or not?

Comment: I don't believe ajax is called in the console it just says "Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/store.php?"

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Button is pressed');
        var clickBtnName = $(this).attr('name');
        var ajaxurl = 'http://127.0.0.1/SQLDeleteHandler.php';
        var data = {'id': clickBtnName};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            window.location.href="http://localhost/store.php";
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm very strange, it seems it still doesn't work , I click the button and I don't even get the alert